# Octave- Negative step function

Tags: octave

I'm trying to write a code to plot a negative step function (a function which is equal to zero when t*< t and equals a certain value when t>=t*). I would like to have a code where I could change by myself the amplitude of the step and the time at which the step occurs. I tried the following function but it does not suit what I'm looking for:

```
  x = zeros (size (t));
  ind2= t<1000;
  x(ind2)=0;
  ind = t >= 1000 & t < inf;
  x(ind) = -20*10^-5;
  endfunction
```

Could someone suggest me and answer ? Thank you

Comment: Why does it not suit? What is the problem with the code? It has some redundancies, but should work. Note that you can write `-20e-5`, you don’t need to do `-20*10^-5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
clear;clf;

## usage: Pristep = Heaviside (t,tstar,amplitude)
##
##
function Pristep = Heaviside (t,tstar,amplitude)
  Pristep=zeros(size(t));Heavisideon=find(t>tstar)
  Pristep(Heavisideon)=amplitude*ones(size(Heavisideon));
endfunction

%% example:

nt=101;t=linspace(-10,10,nt);
plot(t,Heaviside(t,pi,-exp(1)))
```

Comment: You can remove `find` and `ones`: `Pristep(t>tstar)=amplitude` will work.

Comment: No it wouldn't work because I don't have the package which contains the Heaviside function.

Comment: Sorry, the Heaviside function is part of the script I gave you (starting with the three lines of comments), you should be able to cut and paste what I wrote, and it will run as is.